# Polymer-ajax mysterious binding

Tags: ajax, bind, polymer

I have a beginner (sorry) question on the element polymer-ajax.

In the file "polymer-ajax.html" ([a link](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-ajax/blob/master/polymer-ajax.html)), line 249 there is a mysterious binding :

```
args.callback = this.receive.bind(this);
```

What is this ?
The callback could not work without it ? Why ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bind` is a basic JavaScript built-in that attaches a context to a function. IOW, when `args.callback` is invoked, the `this` value will be the `this` passed to `bind`. See here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Thanks a lot ... 
I have to deal with a similary pb in my own code.